# filter excel list by formula instead of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

If I have a column in excel, with the following formulas, would it be possible to filter it?  In this case, the values are all 7, but could I filter by the explicit formula?

```
=2+7
=3+4
=2+7
7
=1+6
7
=2+7
=8-1
=ROUND(SQRT(52),0)
```

In my real world example, I have a list with a variety of formulae in that I want to filter.  This is just a simple way of illustrating the goal.

People of the future: if you're having a the same problem and there's no solution in the comments, a workaround is to highlight the column, and Find and Replace "=" with an unused character or string (I use "~#|") and then after all is done, replace back. It's awkward, but it works

Comment: Unclear what are you asking,  what filtering do you need?  If you apply the Filter,  you are able to select all "7" data

Comment: I want to filter by the explicit formula, not the resulting value

"=1+6" should be a separate item than "=1+7"

Comment: To be clear you want to sort by the first charterer after the "="

Comment: If you dont want excel to treat those as a formula, you can always insert a `'` before `=`

Comment: @Bilo I know that, I but I just want to filter a list by the formula.  I know I can "un-formula" it by find and replace, I but I want to be able to filter formulas on the fly

Comment: You could have an additional column that has the same formulas formatted as text and then sort by that column

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using VBA. I am sure this is not the most efficient solution but may be a starting point for something more eloquent.

Adds a ' to each cell

```
Sub MarkUp()

Dim aCell As Range For Each aCell In Selection
       aCell = "'" & aCell.Formula

     Next

End Sub
```

Sorts the Range

```
Private Sub Sort()

Dim aRange As Range
 Dim aCell As Range

Set aRange = Selection
 Set aCell = ActiveCell

 aRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

End Sub
```

Cleans Up

```
Private Sub CleanUp()

Dim aCell As Range For Each aCell In Selection
      aCell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(aCell, "'", "")

    Next

End Sub
```

And

> ```
> Sub SortFormulas()
>
> MarkUp
> Sort
> CleanUp
>
> End Sub
> ```